# Kafka Streams: How to use persistentKeyValueStore to reload existing messages from disk?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

My code is currently using an InMemoryKeyValueStore, which avoids any persistence to disk or to kafka. 
I want to use rocksdb (Stores.persistentKeyValueStore) so that the app will reload state from disk. I'm trying to implement this, and I'm very new to Kafka and the streams API. Would appreciate help on how I might make changes, while I still try to understand stuff as I go.

I tried to create the state store here:

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> store =
                Stores.<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeKey), Serdes.String(), valueSerde);
```

How do I register it with the streams builder?

Existing code which uses the inMemoryKeyValueStore:

```
   static StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> makeStoreBuilder(
            final String storeKey,
            final Serde<LinkedList<StoreItem>> valueSerde,
            final boolean loggingDisabled) {

        final StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, LinkedList<StoreItem>>> storeBuilder =
                Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(storeKey), Serdes.String(), valueSerde);
        return storeBuilder;
    }
```

I need to ensure that the streams app will not end up missing existing messages in the log topic each time it restarts.

Comment: `My code is currently using an InMemoryKeyValueStore, which avoids any persistence to disk or to kafka.` -- not sure what you mean by "or to Kafka" -- in-memory or persistent does not impact if a store is backed by a changelog topic in the Kafka cluster, but logging can be enabled or disabled for both types of stores, depending if you want the store to be fault-tolerant or not. Note, that a persistent store does NOT make a store fault tolerant!

Answer (score 0):

> How do I register it with the streams builder?

By calling `StreamsBuilder#addStateStore()`.

https://kafka.apache.org/22/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsBuilder.html#addStateStore-org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StoreBuilder-

See `StateStoresInTheDSLIntegrationTest` at https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples fro an end-to-end demo application.

Answer (score 0):

You use a persistent store the exact some way as an in-memory store. The store takes care of the rest and you don't need to worry about loading data etc. You just use it.